# Get a list of dictionary from an XML and value of single items

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to get information in an XML file. I am trying to do that with ElementTree, however it seems that what I am currently doing breaks the xml structure in python.

Here there is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase>
    <Activities>
        <Activity>
            <Id>2018-05-23</Id>
            <Lap>
                <TotalTimeSeconds>19204.0</TotalTimeSeconds>
                <MaximumHeartRateBpm>
                    <Value>137</Value>
                </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
                <Track>
                    <Trackpoint>
                        <Time>2018-05-23</Time>
                        <HeartRateBpm>
                            <Value>79</Value>
                        </HeartRateBpm>
                        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
                    </Trackpoint>
                    <Trackpoint>
                        <Time>2018-05-23</Time>
                        <HeartRateBpm>
                            <Value>80</Value>
                        </HeartRateBpm>
                        <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
                    </Trackpoint>
                </Track>
            </Lap>            
        </Activity>
    </Activities>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

My really simple code is the following:

```
e = ET.parse('fileName.xml').getroot()
e = e.find('./Activities/Activity/Lap/Track')    
print(e)
```

This code returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

I have followed the documentation and some question on stack, as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). My final output would be some variables that contain the one time information as: MaximumHeartRateBpm, TotalTimeSeconds and Id. Moreover I would like to get a list of dictionaries for the Track item with the following structure:

```
[{"Time": val, "HeartRateBpm": val, "SensorState": val},
...,
{"Time": val, "HeartRateBpm": val, "SensorState": val}]
```

I cannot attempt the second one as I am not able to look into the xml.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `e`  after the execution of the _first_ statement? Is it a `None` by chance? Also, what is the value of `ET.parse('fileName.xml')`? Is _that one_ a `None` by chance?

Comment: @DyZ If i print e after reading the xml I get this: "<Element TrainingCenterDatabase' at 0x0000022AF1469B38>"

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I get the printout `<Element 'Track' at 0x7f7e3712ca48>` on the last line of your snippet.